# SQL Server 2012 authentication mode refuses to connect

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to connect to the sql server 2012 using `SQL Server Authentication` but it doesn't work .

When I installed the SQL server I entered the username `root` and password `root` , however when 
I try to connect , I get this :

[image]

Followed by

[image]

Any idea how to resolve this annoying problem ?

Much appreciated

Comment: can you try login name 'sa' and your password. I guess sa is the default login name

Comment: @mhn: Worked great ! Make it an answer and I'll choose it as best answer . I have no idea what it worked :)

Comment: When you installed SQL Server it didn't ask for user and password, it asked for password for built-in system account (user `sa`) and confirm password was second field. You weren't reading carefully ;)

Comment: http://www.pinaldave.com/bimg/2008small/200815.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try login name 'sa' and your password . sa is default login name for Sql server .